# two <nav> elements - desktop vs. mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From what I've researched it appears as if it is acceptable to use two `<nav>` elements for things such has secondary menu's, or submenus. And that's understandable.

But what about using two `<nav>` elements with identical links for the differences of desktop vs. mobile? Is it considered bad practice, or are there any disadvantages (penalties) for doing such? I know it would go against "dry" coding, but anything else?

** Background - I'm considering this approach because I cannot seem to get the mobile menu (activated by hamburger button click) to "fade" in and out, and still have everything function correctly if the browser is resized for any reason. I feel it's unlikely that a resizing would occur, but I run into errors when attempting to use "visibility" properties, or "display" properties, or jQuery "fades" and Javascript "animations" without duplicating the `<nav>` element, and targeting one without the other. Side note, I can get it to work just fine with one `<nav>` and any of the "slide" effects, it's only with trying to accomplish a "fade" effect.

Comment: This question is opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Actually, you probably should be using a transition, not an animation for fade in/out effects.

Comment: Not to derail your initial question, but the issue you're experiencing with the fading is exactly what SO is good at helping with.  If you can get a minimal demo together, I'm sure we could help you figure out how to reduce it down to one `nav` and have the fade effect.

Comment: you're asking two different broad topics without providing a clear, short and concise description of the problem you're facing. It sounds like your problem is easily solvable by a front-end developer, but you will have to provide code samples/a fiddle/a code snippet (the latter being preferable)

Comment: @Paulie_D - Sorry, I don't mean to be off-topic. I didn't think asking what the "disadvantages" are would be an opinion.

Comment: Who defines what is an "advantage/disadvantage"? Since there is no **quantifiable** answer, it's always subjective and so opinion based. Still, no harm done.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Good point!

Comment: @DarrellO. : you might find the answer to what you're looking for in my answer below, but still consider re-writing your question to make it as specific as possible to help others that might have the same problem. For example "change hamburger menu animation from a slide to a fade". Asking whether having an element twice is indeed opinion based as it's not strictly prohibited by the HTML Standard therefore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, if the markup needed for the mobile nav and the full-width nav is different, or the nav markup needs to be in different places (using third party plugins for off-screen navigation is one use case), I'll happily place two sets of markup on my page.  Barring those two cases, I'll almost always try to reuse my markup.

Comment: I am trying to position the nav in two different places. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, duplicating an element for the sake of repositioning/visual styling desktop/mobile is almost never necessary.

Instead, keep the nav container once, and either use two versions of your links, or use media queries to reposition / restyle your element.

Remember, using pure CSS to handle screen sizes and responsive has the added benefit of not having to listen for Window resize events thus making your website faster, and your work easier.

```
<nav>
<ul class="links">
  <li>
    <a href="#">link one</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="links mobile">
  <li>
    <a href="#">link one</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

You're mentioning trying to make a hamburger menu to work, I would strongly advise using the [bootstrap navigation](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/) which is working fine. (and fading is easily implementable with the additional fade HTML classes)

I add below a snippet that shows the bootstrap hamburger menu, but implemented with a fade.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse fade in">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I never considered this approach. This may work. I'm going to put together a couple of examples of my issue(s) to share, and test this along the way. I'll let you know soon if this works.

Comment: In my snippet the CSS magic is hidden in the bootstrap.min.css file loaded, but if you want to understand the mechanics of it let me know and I'll edit my reply.